# About inserting values into an array

Tags: arrays, shell

I have a question about inserting values into array. I am writing a for loop to insert 1 to 10 integer to an array. The array name is `drivelist`, and the integer variable is `loc`.

```
drivelist=($drivelist $loc)
```

But the code line is faulty; it just saves the first value and last value.
However, if I modify the code like this, then it works correctly:

```
drivelist=( ${drivelist[@]} $loc )
```

Why can the faulty code just save two values?

Answer (score 5):

You only get two items in the array because `$drivelist` is equivalent to `${drivelist[0]}`, so there's only that item and `$loc` in the list reassigned to the array.

You could also use `drivelist+=($loc)` to add items to an array one at a time:

```
drivelist=()
for loc in $(seq 1 10)
do
    drivelist+=($loc)
done

printf "[%s]\n" "${drivelist[@]}"
```

Sample output:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[10]
```

Of course, for this exercise, it would be simpler and sufficient to use:

```
drivelist=( $(seq 1 10) )
```

where the spaces around the parentheses are optional.  The first parenthesis starts an array assignment; the `$(...)` runs the command and splits the output into words which are assigned to elements of the array, and the final parenthesis closes the array assignment.

Comment: is there anyway to remove duplicates?

Comment: There are ways of removing duplicates.  That's a different question though.